Invoke Change Owner QuickAction from LWC
I've created a custom Account page using LWC and lightning-record-edit-form, but the Account Owner field is not editable through the lightning-input-field, so I would like to have a custom button to invoke the standard change owner modal from Salesforce.
I tried follow this example, but the modal never loads.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_email_quick_actions.htm
That's what I tried:
var pageRef = {
    type: "standard__quickAction",
    attributes: {
        apiName: "Account.ChangeOwnerOne"
    },
    state: {
        recordId: '0010500000gxZBVAA2'
    }
};

this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageRef);

I know I can build a custom modal to change the owner, but I would like to use the standard one if possible, any one knows if is that possible?

Invoking the standard change owner modal from a custom button in an LWC is not directly supported. The example you've followed is for using email quick actions, which is different from invoking a change owner modal.
